# Try to validate a xml-file by more than one xsd-file

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I try to validate a xml-file aganist two xsd-files, but I get every time an error on validation. I use the "xml copy editor" to validate. I do not know, if this is a problem of my xml/xsd or the program (which maybe can not validate aganist multiple xsd!?). Can anybody help?

I try to follow the example on [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760014/including-importing-local-schemas-that-have-namespaces/).

XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PostAdress xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="D:\XML\XSD1.xsd">
    <Meta>
        <Name>Hallo</Name>
    </Meta>
</PostAdress>
```

XSD1.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs2="http://aa.bb.cc">
    <xs:import namespace="http://aa.bb.cc" schemaLocation="D:\XML\XSD0.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="PostAdress">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Meta" type="xs2:Adress" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XSD0.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://aa.bb.cc">
  <xs:element name="Adress">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

PS: I get the error: "Error at line 7: column 96: type 'http://aa.bb.cc:Adress' not found." I think the program means Line 7 in XSD1.xsd.

PS2: I try also to run a small VB.net-App for validation. I get nearly the same error message. So, I think there is a problem with the files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a file uri when importing the *other* xsd scheme.
Try to replace the row

```
<xs:import namespace="http://aa.bb.cc" schemaLocation="D:\XML\XSD0.xsd" />
```

with this one

```
<xs:import namespace="http://aa.bb.cc" schemaLocation="file:D:/XML/XSD0.xsd" />
```

in your XSD1.xsd scheme

Comment: I tried your solution, but with same result - same error message.

Comment: it seems to me that yor _validator_ doesn't load the XSD0.xsd file, as a last resort try to use a relative uri/path in the schemaLocation attribute, i.e. schemaLocation='./XSD0.xsd'

Comment: Same result. I think, like you, it is maybe a problem of the program. Do you know some freeware tool for windows, which can handle multiple xsd-files?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know any free tool for that work, actually, I usually use eclipse to validate xml documents.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it also with notepad++, with the same result.  So, I think it is maybe not problem of two xsd-files. So I put all the nessesary content in one xsd and....same error. After that I look a little bit closer to my xsd-file and I found the mistake. I had this structure:

Instance.xml >> XSD1.xsd >> XSD0.xsd
Usage "PostAdress" >> Definition of "PostAdress" by using of "Adress" as **type** >> Definition of "Adress"

The wrong line was by the definition of the "Adress". I wrote...

```
  <xs:element name="Adress">
    <xs:complexType>
      ...
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

But correct is:

```
   <xs:complexType name="Adress">
      <xs:sequence>
      ...
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
```

So my files look like:

XSD1.xsd:

```
<xs:element name="PostAdress">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Meta" type="andererNs:Adress" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

And XSD0.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://aa.bb.cc">

   <xs:complexType name="Adress">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

At the end, it is possible to validate with more than one xsd-file with the program "xml copy editor" (or notepad++). Also, relative file names are good enough, if the files are in the same folder.

Thanks to the helpers.